# Select "toolbar-title" within shadow root of ion-title via css

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, shadow-dom

In Ionic, the ion-title component has the content encapsulated in an extra div within its shadow-dom.
This div has the class .toolbar-title set. How can i select this div via scss-selector to change its overflow behavior?

[image]

I tried:

```
.toolbar-title { ... }
ion-title .toolbar-title
ion-title::shadow .toolbar-title { ... }
ion-title::shadow(div) { ... }
```

and a lot other combinations including :host & ::ng-deep selectors.

And, yes i know , ::shadow and ng-deep is deprectaded.

I also know that ionic has introduced css-variables for this purposes, but unfortunatley not for the overflow attribute.

THX in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of shadowDOM is you can't touch its content with CSS from the outside.

It is an `open` shadowDOM, so you can change it with JavaScript.

```js
document.querySelector("ion-title")
        .shadowRoot
        .querySelector(".toolbar-title")
        .style
        .overflow = "initial";
```

Comment: Thx! Do you know what the reason for this constraint is? Is it a technical thing or by design?

Comment: That is the whole concept of shadowDOM: **encapsulation**. Note: The "Web Components" standard has 3 core technologies: Custom Elements API, shadowDOM and Templates. Each can be used without the others. So you can create Custom Elements *without* shadowDOM. CSS will then be applied. Ionic decided to use shadowDOM for its components.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic v6 allows you to target and modify shadowDOM contents with CSS. See https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-shadow-parts

However, the element you want to select inside the shadowDOM needs to expose a `part` attribute. For instance the `ion-select` element:

```
<ion-select>
  #shadow-root
  <div part="placeholder" class="select-text select-placeholder"></div>
  <div part="icon" class="select-icon"></div>
</ion-select>
```

You can select the `placeholder` element with:

```
ion-select::part(placeholder) {
  color: blue;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Unfortunately**, the `ion-title` element **does not expose any shadow parts**. You need to wrap the contents of `ion-title` in a container to be able to modify them:

```
<ion-title>
  <div class="content">
    <img src="..." />
    Hello World!
  </div>
</ion-title>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-title-modification-8a1qst